# Internet Explorer Compatibility issue with web page

Tags: asp.net, web, styles, internet-explorer-11

I am developing a .NET application for my clients. One of my pages I have included a `RadDatePicker` and several other input methods. When I run my project it occurs an error only in Internet Explorer web browser (IE version 11.0.9600.18282).

When I access to the web page from the local host it displays the page as the top part of the image below which is correct.But if I access my localhost from another computer that is connected to the same network, it displays the web page as in the second part of the image with some errors in the style.

I already checked the versions of both web browsers and rendering models and compatibility view settings and still I have no idea where it went wrong.

Can you please help me with that.

[image]